# Awk: How do you build a string variable with new lines?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, busybox

I am trying to do the following:

result of `ls -l` on a folder:

```
-rw-rw-r--   1 root  root  100  May 23 09:45 filename1
-rw-rw-r--   1 root  root  200  May 23 09:45 filename2
-rw-rw-r--   1 root  root  500  May 23 09:46 filename3
```

Now I want to pass this through awk to do the following:

```
800 bytes, files:
filename1
filename2
filename3
```

So far I can get awk to add up the bytes:

```
output=`ls -l /some/folder/ | awk 'START {total = 0}; {total += $5} END{print total}'`
```

This simple gives: `800`

Now I want to start building up the output string, so I am trying to get a list of filenames (column $9 I think), I am trying like this:

```
output=`ls -l /some/folder/ | awk 'START {total = 0; files=""}; {total += $5 files="\n" files $9} END{print total "files:" files}'`
```

`echo $output` gives the following:

`800 filename1 filename2 filename3`

I want it to show:

```
800
filename1
filename2
filename3
```

I don't understand why the lines are not split into new lines?

Comment: try double quoting `"$output"`

Comment: I suggest to use: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%s %f\n"`

Comment: oh come on....seriously, -1?... this question is the definition of a good question - it shows that I have made an effort, its a specific issue, I have minimal example code and outputs....yeah, sure I am thick as 2 short planks for not knowing what I am doing, but that's the point of asking a question... it really makes me not want to use SO anymore when the "critics" are so harsh. I don't care about the points.. its just a matter of 'why' are there so many people here ready to -1 and vote-to-close everything...   bahh, anyway - thanks very much to the actual contributors here :)

Comment: @PS. Yeah, that worked! thanks... although I totally don't get why. If you want to stick it down as an answer i'll happily mark it up.

Comment: @Cyrus I am using a cut-down version of bash (busybox) embedded and it does not appear to support the "printf" part of your suggestion : (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White space, including newlines are collapsed when you don't quote your variables in the shell, so a simple fix to what you've done would be to use `echo "$output"`.

That said, I would recommend against using `ls -l` to get your file names and their sizes, as the tool is not designed to be parsed. Any column-based approach will break when you have an interesting filename.

Using GNU `stat` allows you to get the file sizes and control the output, using null bytes `\0` to make the names safe to parse:

```
stat --printf '%s\0%n\0' * | awk -v RS='\0' '
NR % 2 { total += $0; next } # add to total on odd lines, skip to next line
{ files[++n] = $0 }          # save file names on other (even) lines
END { print total, "bytes, files:"; for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) print files[i] }'
```

If you can't use `stat --printf`, then you can use `stat -c` and hope that no-one put a newline in a filename:

```
stat -c '%s %n' * | awk '{ total += $1; files[NR] = substr($0, length($1) + 2) } 
END { print total, "bytes, files:"; for (i = 1; i <= NR; ++i) print files[i] }'
```

The first field contains the name and the rest of the line is the filename, so `substr` is used to get that part.

The `*` passed as an argument to `stat` is expanded by the shell to the full list of files in the current directory. You can get the files in another directory by passing `/path/to/dir/*`, or by first `cd`ing to the destination. You could also use a loop, for example:

```
for dir in dir1 dir2 dir3; do
    ( cd "$dir" && stat -c '%s %n' * | awk '...')
done
```

Here I used a `( subshell )` as a lazy way of returning to the original directory after each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for that and the nice details proposed solution +1, again, my busybox stat does not support --printf... I am going to add that to the detail of my question. A bit annoying for me that I can't use these features. But the quote around the $output works nicely : )

Comment: No problem. I've edited to add a version that works with `stat -c`, which I think is more widely supported.

Comment: Thanks brilliant! - works nicely : ) ... I tried to get this command to work for a specific directory, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that. So I can get around it by cd'ing to the directory in question - but I want to run this on 4-5 different dirs. Can you do something like: "`stat <specify dir path> --printf....`"? I tried using -f, but I think that is for specific file and not folder.

Comment: @code_fodder I've updated my answer to show some options.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -l | awk 'NR > 1 {s+=$5; f=f"\n"$NF} END{print s,f}'
```

The first line in the output of `ls -l` is ignored (`NR > 1`). `5th` field (file size) in all the lines are added up in a variable `s`. Filenames are appended to variable `f` (separated by newline). In the `END` block, print `s` and `f`.

**Sample:**

```
AMD$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 165 May 24 08:23 ff
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 165 May 24 08:23 gg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 165 May 24 08:23 hh

AMD$ ls -l | awk 'NR > 1 {s+=$5; f=f"\n"$NF} END{print s,f}'
495
ff
gg
hh
```

If you want to save this into a variable and print out later:

```
var=$(ls -l | awk 'NR > 1 {s+=$5; f=f"\n"$NF} END{print s,f}')
echo "$var"
```

Comment: Thanks - this explains it very well : )   +1 (negative vote is not from me and should not be there IMO as this answers the question nicely).

Answer (score 1):

To preserve the structure of the variable, it should be double quoted.

Example:

Multiline variable:

```
x='hey
> there'
```

Without quoting:

```
echo $x
hey there
```

Double quoted:

```
echo "$x"
hey
there
```